# Get the most common items in List<T> and sort after that

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq

I have a `List<T>` of an object/class which has already been filled with data from a SQL database. What I want to do is to find out who the most common user in this table is and sort the new list based on and starting on the most common user

I have no idea how to style a table here on Stackoverflow so you have to bear with me.

The database table can for example look like this:

```
id - userID - randomColumn - randomColumn2
1 - 2 - ExampleText - ExampleText
2 - 2 - ExampleText - ExampleText
3 - 1 - ExampleText - ExampleText
4 - 3 - ExampleText - ExampleText
5 - 2 - ExampleText - ExampleText
6 - 1 - ExampleText - ExampleText
```

I want to use either LINQ or SQL to format this so I get a list that looks like this

```
userID - amountColumn - randomColumn
2 - 3 - ExampleText
1 - 2 - ExampleText
3 - 1 - ExampleText
```

Comment: Did you try [group by](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-to-DataSets-Grouping-c62703ea)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `GroupBy` extension method provided by LINQ.

```
// Pseudo code
var grouped = list.GroupBy(item => item.UserID);
```

You can then call `OrderByDescending` to sort your results:

```
var sorted = grouped.OrderByDescending(group => group.Count());
```

Comment: You would also want an `OrderBy` call afterwords.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `GroupBy` method in linq to group by the users, then order by the count of the users, then select the ordered items.

```
var grouped = list.GroupBy(g => g.UserID)
                  .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count)
                  .Select(g => g);
```

As mentioned in the comments, this will return a list of groups. To get those into one "flat" list, you can use `SelectMany`:

```
var items = grouped.SelectMany(g => g);
```

`items` will then be a single list of users.

Comment: Why `Select(g => g)`?

Comment: Don't know why so many upvotes, but that will return sequence of groups

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Which should be fine; the OP can trivially manipulate it to exactly what he wants, given that we don't know exactly what he wants.  The part that he doesn't know how to do is done, which is sufficient for a good answer.

Comment: @Servy arguable. Very arguable. then answer is - use `Enumerable.GroupBy`. OP can use appropriate column and manipulate results

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Sure.  You sound like you think that's absurd.  That's all the OP really needed to hear.

Comment: @MariusSchulz I was thinking of projecting it to a flat list. As per my edit, I actually meant `Aggregate`.

Comment: @DaveZych That's pretty horrible practice.  If you want to put all of the items in a sequence into a list just use `ToList` rather than using a method like `Aggregate` purely to perform side effects on each iteration.

Comment: @Servy what do you mean? Calling `ToList` on an `IGrouping` returns the grouping as a list.

Comment: @DaveZych If you want to flatten a sequence there is an operator for that too.

Comment: @Servy mmmm... I'm guessing you're talking about `SelectMany`. You're right, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to group items by `userID`. Then project each group into anonymous type (or some specific type if you have one) by selecting grouping key, count of items in group and value of random column of first item in group. Last step is ordering results by items count property of projected groups:

```
var query = list.GroupBy(u => u.userID)                  
                .Select(g => new {
                     userID = g.Key,
                     amountColumn = g.Count(),
                     randomColumn = g.First().randomColumn
                 }).OrderByDescending(x => x.amountColumn);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need the [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function :

```
users.GroupBy(n => n.userID)
   .Select(n => new {userID = n.Key, amountColumn = n.Count()})
   .OrderByDescending(n => n.amountColumn);
```

Comment: You should use the `Key` property of the group to access the key, not the value of the first item in the group.

Answer (score 0):

SQL will be:

```
SELECT userID, Count(UserID) AS Total , randomColumn
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY userID,randomColumn
ORDER BY Total
```

Comment: That does not work you can not order or group by an aggregate function unless the result is part of a subquery.

Comment: Not likely unless sql did a change in specs I do not have.

Comment: @IrfanTahirKheli I've tried it and it works great. But how would you do if I wanted to for example add another table in that uses that userID, like an user table.

Comment: @HenrikP : can you create a fiddle for your senario. Or better explain your question?

Comment: @IrfanTahirKheli Like a normal database relationship : SELECT * FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.foreignID = table2.id. But making it work with what you posted

Comment: @HenrikP : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6559d/1 .. check this.. hope this is what you looking for.

Comment: @IrfanTahirKheli But how do you SELECT something from the other table? Like how do you select that category column in UserTest ut

Comment: @HenrikP : You can select any column, You would need to include all the column you select in the Group By clause.